# SQL Server Update Statement via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-update

I am currently using the following piece of code of testing purposes.

```
$database = 'REMOVED'
$server = 'REMOVED'
$SQLServer = "REMOVED"
$SQLDBName = "REMOVED"
$SQLuser = "REMOVED"
$SQLpassword = "REMOVED"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
$SQLDBName; User ID = $SQLuser; Password = $SQLpassword;"

$SqlConnection.Open()
$update = @"
   update ca_contact set last_name='Rech' where userid='OR010101'
"@

  $dbwrite = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
  $dbwrite.CommandText = $update
  $dbwrite.ExecuteNonQuery() 

$Sqlconnection.Close()
```

I am getting a return value of '1' which tells me that the statement appears to be working. But the value never gets written to the database when viewing via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: maybe there is no userid OR010101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be how you are building the connection string.. I am unsure.. but this should work.

```
$SQLServer = "tcp:ServerName.Domain.com"
$SQLDB = 'DB_name'
$Password = "VeryComplexPassword"
$USer = "Sophisticated_User"

$cn = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDB;User Id=$User;Password=$Password;");
$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "DataObject"
$q = 
@"
   UPDATE [DB_Name].[schema].[Table_Name]
   SET Updated_Column =  'New_Value'
   WHERE Filter_Column = 'Filter_Criteria'
"@
$da = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($q, $cn)
$da.Fill($ds)
```